# Re-executing ListView Converter in a time interval

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to re-execute the converter of a specific ListView's column, say each second. The value of the bound property does not change. So I'm not able to use ObservableCollection or trigger. Is it possible to rerun the converter?

Comment: If the bound property doesn't change, why do you want to rerun the converter? Wouldn't it return with the same value always?

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi The column in the listview shows the status of the availability of the user in the system by a color. It is bound to the last seen time of the user. The converter translates the difference between the last seen time of the user and the current time to a color. So although the value doesn't change but the return value of the converter may change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your `ListView`'s Model does(and it should) implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, to force the call to the converter you could simply set a timer and call the `OnPropertyChanged("NameOfProperty");` each 1 sec, where `NameOfProperty` is the name of the property your `ListView`'s column is bond to:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {            
        OnPropertyChanged("NameOfProperty");
    }
```